# set remote sharing prefs in terminal

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop

I am admin for department and I want to batch change the "show remote management status in menu bar" so that I don't have to log in to each machine and set it.

I have ARD so I can run a terminal command across all machines I just can't seem to find out how to set that option through the terminal

Could anyone tell me how to do that ? or if it's even possible ?

Comment: This will certainly be possible. I'll bookmark it to come back, but you'll either need to find the `defaults write com.apple.whatever` preference that needs to be written to enable or suppress the menu bar or just have your script install a profile to control the preference systematically rather than graphically.

Comment: Have you tried `defaults write  /Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteManagement LoadRemoteManagementMenuExtra -bool true`?

Comment: i have not but i could try that

Answer (score 1):

The easiest tool to set these settings programatically is the kickstart script that Apple ships:

> sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -help

Do read the help since, it warns ***This script can be used to grant very permissive incoming access permissions.  Do not use the -activate and -configure features unless
you know exactly what you're doing.***

That being said, you will want to set a variable $ObserveUser for each user that should be shown a menu indication that screen observation is in progress:

> sudo kickstart -configure -access -on -privs -ShowObserve -users $ObserveUser